# How do I revert the action of xxd -r -p text_dump > binary_dump?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, binary, hex

How do I reverse the action of (xxd -r -p text_dump > binary_dump). If I have a file, text_dump, xxd -r -p text_dump > binary_dump gives me a binary file(binary_dump). How do I revert the action by converting the binary_dump to text_dump??

Comment: Does `xxd -p binary_dump` give you what you want ?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Or maybe no command does actually, coz I have tried all that I can

Comment: Can you give a sample of text_dump ?